# when to standard and text checkpoint in qtp

Tags: qtp

i am new to qtp, i confused with standard checkpoint and text checkpoint, some times standard checkpoint reads all text content in the window, but text doesn't read text content.

so please help me in what situation the standard and text checkpoint are used

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the values of specific properties using QTP's normal property mechanism you should use a standard checkpoint.

Text checkpoints on the other hand used either Windows API or [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) to get the text (you can control which from **Tools -> Options -> General -> Text Recognition**), and I would use it only if you can't get what you want from the standard checkpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Standard check point is mainly used to check the variety of object such as button ,radio button check box etc.

more details check this link http://qtp.blogspot.in/2007/08/qtp-tutorials-4-standard-checkpoint.html

Text check point is used to check the text contents.

more details check this link http://qtp.blogspot.in/2007/08/qtp-tutorials-9-text-checkpoint.html